# ImageIcon is not showing as an icon

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to set a set of images as an icon for my frames.It works without any issues if i'm using `getClass.getResource(path)` instead but i need this code to run in a static method so i can't use getClass(). What's the big difference and why does it's not working with just a path?

```
        final ImageIcon icon_x16 = new ImageIcon( "Icons/icon_x16.png");
        final ImageIcon icon_x20 = new ImageIcon( "Icons/icon_x20.png");
        final ImageIcon icon_x32 = new ImageIcon( "Icons/icon_x32.png");
        final ImageIcon icon_x40 = new ImageIcon( "Icons/icon_x40.png");
        final ImageIcon icon_x64 = new ImageIcon( "Icons/icon_x64.png");
        final ImageIcon icon_x256 = new ImageIcon( "Icons/icon_x256.png");
        final List<Image> icons = new ArrayList<Image>();
        icons.add(icon_x16.getImage());
        icons.add(icon_x20.getImage());
        icons.add(icon_x32.getImage());
        icons.add(icon_x40.getImage());
        icons.add(icon_x64.getImage());
        icons.add(icon_x256.getImage());
        frame.setIconImages(icons);
```

Comment: `instead but i need this code to run in a static method so i can't use getClass()` - Yes, you can,  `YourAwesomeClass.class.getResource(...)`

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` is looking for a file on the file system.  Unless you provide a an absolute path, it will be looking from the location that the app was executed from, which won't help you in this case

Comment: *but i need this code to run in a static method* - no you don't. This indicates poor program design. There is no need for your methods to be static.

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer . `YourAwesomeClass.class.getResource(...)` solved my problem and i also realised that my .class files are stored in a diffent folder so the path is wrong.

Comment: @camickr Yes, thank you for pointing it. I am a newbie trying to make my university project so my program design is not the best.

Comment: @ArtsiomSiarheyeu *I am a newbie* - not an excuse. All you need to do is read any text book or tutorial to find better structured code.  . For example start with the `LabelDemo` example found in the tutorial on [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). Keep a link to the entire tutorial handy for all Swing basics.